# Vim: How do I chdir to path in a variable

Tags: vim

I have a path stored in a variable (say l:s) and want to execute lcd l:s in a vim script, but it tells me the path "l:s" doesn't exist.  What is the problem here, because vim resolves variable names in other ex commands just fine (echo, etc.).  I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exe` and construct the command:

```
let s:some_dir_name = "foo"
exe "lcd " . s:some_dir_name
```

That'll evaluate the variable `s:some_dir_name` and execute the command `lcd foo`.

(I didn't use `l:s` from your question because that's not a legal variable name, but I think you get the idea.)

Comment: Thanks!  This is a better answer.  I actually learned about :execute a few weeks ago.  l:s isn't a legal variable name?  I thought it named a "local" variable named "s".  Vim variables sure are weird.

Answer (score 1):

Vim lets you set environment variables within a script, and these work with :cd and :lcd.  For example:

```
function foo()
    let $SOME_PATH = '/some/path'
    lcd $SOME_PATH
endfunction
```