# Pass variable to tabnew

Tags: vim

I have a variable set like so:

```
let filename="/tmp/" . system('date +"%Y%m%d"') . ".txt"
```

How do I open a new buffer using that variable as filename, like `tabnew /tmp/20130117.txt`

Answer (score 3):

No system call needed, although vim's docs do mention that strftime isn't available on all systems (I assume only some esoteric ones):

```
if exists('*strftime')
  let fn = strftime('/tmp/%Y%m%d')
  exe "tabnew" fn
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from [Vim: How do I chdir to path in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518771/vim-how-do-i-chdir-to-path-in-a-variable?rq=1), I did:

```
let $FILENAME="/tmp/" . system('date +"%Y%m%d"')
tabnew $FILENAME
```

I just need to figure out how to remove the "@" character at the end of the string output of the system function.

Comment: You can use `system('date +"%Y%m%d" | tr -d "\n"')` to remove the trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In vim, I did this:

`substitute($FILENAME, "\n", "", "g")`